# React Js / Semantic React / button display

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a problem leaving my button text on just one line I used the inline display but it didn't work

> ```
>   <ButtonRegister> Não tem uma conta? <h5>Registre-se </h5></ButtonRegister>
> ```

style:

```
export const ButtonRegister = styled(Button)`
display: inline !important;
background: transparent !important;
color: #000 !important;
text-align: center !important;
align-items: center;
padding-left: 0 !important;
margin-top: 10px !important;
width: 100%;
&:hover {
    background: transparent !important;
    color: #21deff !important;
}
```

code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/old-platform-u9lqq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `h5` display: inline, or inline-block. By default `h5` is display: block. That's why it is on different line